# What is the output of this?

Tags: date, output, echo

Sorry to disturb, but I don't know ANYTHING about Java and I just need an answer for this question.

What is the output of this command?

```
date -u +%F | sha1sum | head -c8; echo
```

Again I'm new, and I don't know how this website works either.
I don't know if its Java, PHP, or what.

Comment: `587ed537`.  At least today it is.

Comment: FYI, the code you posted is a pipeline of Unix commands that would be interpreted by a shell (bash, csh, ksh, or a few others).  The output of the `date` command is "piped" to the input of the `sha1sum` command.  The `sha1sum` output is piped to the input of the `head` command, which outputs the first 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's first 8 characters of SHA1-hash of current day string in universal date format(year-month-day). Today is `2014-11-07`, sha1 of this string is `587ed53728cffe06cb912e6c3069800ecd86d9ad`. So if we get only first 8 characters, we will get answer:

```
587ed537
```

In another day it will be different.

Also this question has nothing about JAVA, it's about shell-commands that exists from-the-box in currently popular Linux distributions, and also it's about pipelining command results.